# error 1292 on my website. I don't know where to correct it

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have deleted all the files from my site [www.alquilaenpehuen.com](http://www.alquilaenpehuen.com) to renew the page. Create a new database and import the content (tables) then I uploaded all the files through filezilla, but I can't access the website from any device, although I can access the backend. It is developed in Joomla 4.

On localhost the site works great.

The error it shows is "error 1292" and Hostinger tells me that it is a MySQL problem. But I don't know where to correct it. I will appreciate advice.

My server's version of MySQL on localhost is newer than my hosting provider's.

On localhost the site works fine, but the hosting provider versions cannot be changed.

I don't know where to make modifications so that the site works on the Internet.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using on each server? What version of Joomla?

Comment: `The MySQL Incorrect datetime value error (which is also known as ERROR 1292 ) is triggered when you perform an INSERT statement that contains one or more DATETIME values with the wrong format. `

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider and the developer of the template. Apparently it would be an error in the configuration of the template. Thank you very much for trying to help me.

Comment: Joomla questions are welcome at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.